# Can't get a UIImageView fill the parent UIView with autolayout

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiimageview, autolayout

I'm trying to fill a UIView with a UIImageView using auto layout. I've tried several thing, but the most obvious, equalSize with parent view only works when I set the correct size in "Simulated metric". If I let Freeform (the point of autolayout isn't it ?) I get messed up.

I'm testing on an iPhone 4S and a 6 plus.

Thanks for any leading tracks.

EDIT FOR @mittens

[image]

[image]

I've seen your edit. I still can get it working. As you see I have 4 margin constraints, the same as in your code (I did not need the rest because I only use the main UIView).
Anyway, when I change the size on xcode, the layout is perfect, when I send it to my 4S, I only get Top and left margins.

Comment: All the constraints you have _look_ like they should work, it has `X`, `Y`, `width` & `height` constraints. Perhaps the `UIImageView`'s mode is set to something thats unexpected? When you change it to freeform size does auto layout on the side give you any warnings like a red/yellow arrow/dot-ish kind of thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd double check the constraints on the `UIView` you're trying to fill with the `UIImageView` to make sure it is filling up its parent view as it should be when the storyboard/xib is set to freeform. Also if you're adding/creating the views programmatically double check that the views 'translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`is set to`NO`. That always trips me up.

I made a super quick view and added some constraints to both a view inside the View Controllers view and an Image view to show one way to do it -- hopefully it helps at least a little

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.backdropView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
    self.backdropView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
    self.backdropView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO; // Make sure this is set to NO if the view is being added programmatically
    [self.view addSubview:self.backdropView]; // Always add the view into the hierarchy _before_ constraints are added (again, if creating & adding programmatically)

    NSLayoutConstraint *backdropViewWidth = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.backdropView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.backdropView.superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:0.5 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *backdropViewHeight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.backdropView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.backdropView.superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:0.5 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *backdropViewCenterX = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.backdropView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.backdropView.superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *backdropViewCenterY = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.backdropView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.backdropView.superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1 constant:0];

    [self.backdropView.superview addConstraints:@[backdropViewWidth, backdropViewHeight, backdropViewCenterY, backdropViewCenterX]];

    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
    self.imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:1 alpha:0.5];
    [self.backdropView addSubview:self.imageView];

    NSLayoutConstraint *imageViewTop = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.imageView.superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:8];
    NSLayoutConstraint *imageViewLeft = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.imageView.superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1 constant:8];
    NSLayoutConstraint *imageViewRight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.imageView.superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1 constant:-8];
    NSLayoutConstraint *imageViewBottom = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.imageView.superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:-8];

    [self.imageView.superview addConstraints:@[imageViewTop, imageViewLeft, imageViewRight, imageViewBottom]];

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

That produces [image: View in Portrait in iPhone6 simulator] and [image: View in Landscape in iPhone6 simulator]

Again, hopefully this helps.

EDIT: how to add them in storyboard

Note on photo 3, I select the view I want to constrain and then `shift` select the view I want to constraint it *to*. So I selected the inside `UIView` (because it width/height will be constrained to the parent view) then `shift` selected its parent view (the view it is nested inside of) to enable those options of `Equal Width` & `Equal Height`

Add constraints to UIImageView nested inside the UIView
[image: Add constraints to UIImageView nested inside the UIView]
Center UIView inside its parent view
[image: Center UIView inside its parent view]
Add width/height constraints equal to parent -- Note: I select the view I want to constrain and then `shift` select the view I want to constraint it *to*. So I selected the inside `UIView` (because it width/height will be constrained to the parent view) then `shift` selected its parent view (the view it is nested inside of) to enable those options of `Equal Width` & `Equal Height`
[image: Add width/height constraints equal to parent]
Change multiplier in constraint to be whatever you want, 0.5 in this case
[image: Change multiplier in constraint to be whatever you want, 0.5 in this case]
Celebrate
[image: Celebrate]

Comment: first of all, thanks for the well constructed answer. 
I was actualy doing the same in Storyboard autolayout, and I tried : 
- Center X and Y, then same height same width
- Center X and Y, then constraint Left-Right-Top-Bottom margins
 and some more.

So I tried the programatical way as you showed me, and it's working.

Can you tell me how to do the same in story board ? 
thanks again

Comment: @OthmanTazi edited to add Storyboard screen shots. Not sure if you get notified of edits or not.

Comment: It is basicaly what I,ve done before : right drag cliq to set constraints between the view and the imageview. Can you see my edit, I snapshoted my constraints so you can see.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure but try this in your imageview.

```
[imgView clipToBounds:YES];
```

I hope it's work for you